# Difference between DrawPath and DrawRectangle

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, gdi+

I am drawing lines using both Rectangle and graphicspath in my application and i am facing lose of width and height in drawing when using GraphicsPath rather than using Rectangle.

Below is the sample code which reproduces my issue,

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
   int left = ClientRectangle.X + 40, right = ClientRectangle.Width -80;
   int bottom = ClientRectangle.Height - 80, top = ClientRectangle.Y + 40;
   int borderWidth = 10;

   Rectangle borderrectangle = new Rectangle(left, top, right, bottom);

   Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, borderWidth);

   //Draws lines using Rectangle.
   e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, borderrectangle);

   Point[] points = new Point[]
   {
      new Point(left, top),
      new Point(right, top),
      new Point(right, bottom),
      new Point(left, bottom),
   };

   GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
   path.AddLines(points);
   path.CloseFigure();

   //Draws lines using Path.
   e.Graphics.DrawPath(pen, path);
}
```

Here is the image ,[image]

Inner rectangle is drawn using the DrawPath and outer rectangle is drawn with DrawRectangle.

Could anyone please update me the reason for width and height lose with GraphicsPath drawing, since i have given proper points as like the rectangle?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: with DrawPath you can draw many irregular shapes.

Comment: @LeiYang - yes offcourse. But how to draw without lose in weight and height.

Comment: Look at the constructor of `Rectangle`. The parameters are: `x`, `y`, `width`, `height`

Comment: In addition to comments/answer, try this `Rectangle borderrectangle = new Rectangle(left, top, right-left, bottom-top);` and they would be the same size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are setting the values for your `Rectangle`, you are setting the X and Y coordinates of the top left corner as well as width and height. However, with your `GraphicsPath`, you are explicitly defining every corner as a separate point. To make the `GraphicsPath` draw exactly what the `Rectangle` is, you'll either need to offset your point array coordinates to equal the width and height of the Rectangle:

```
Point[] points = new Point[]
{
   new Point(left, top),
   new Point(right + left, top),
   new Point(right + left, bottom + top),
   new Point(left, bottom + top),
};
```

or construct the Rectangle to treat the `right` and `bottom` as coordinates instead of fixed lengths:

```
Rectangle borderrectangle = new Rectangle(left, top, right - left, bottom - top);
```

Considering that you are treating the values as sides and therefore coordinates, the second option will probably give you the most consistency.

Answer (score 2):

When you create Rectangle you are passing right and bottom *coordinates* as width and height. Check [Rectangle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9wcdy991(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor parameters:

```
public Rectangle(
    int x,
    int y,
    int width,
    int height
)
```

When you use Path, you are drawing it by coordinates and everything is OK. You should create rectangle this way:

```
Rectangle borderrectangle = new Rectangle(left, top, right-left, bottom-top);
```

But make sure that width and height of ClientRectangle are greater than 120